# laravel creation of special table with columns taken from itself

Tags: laravel

I have the following structure for my database:

```
USERS
id
name

PROJECTS
id
name

ACTIVITIES
id
month
user_id
project_id
amount_of_hours
```

I would like to generate a table like this:
user_name,project_name,amount_of_hours in january,amount_of_hours in february,amount_of_hours in march,...

I have tried the following code:

```
$activityList = DB::table('projects')
      ->select( 'users.name','projects.project_name','jan.task_hour','jan.from_otl')
      ->leftjoin('activities', 'projects.id', '=', 'activities.project_id')
      ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'activities.user_id')
      ->leftjoin('activities as jan', function ($join) {
            $join->on('activities.id', '=', 'jan.id')
                 ->where('jan.year', '=', 1);
        })
      ->where('users.id', '=', $id);
      $data = $activityList->get();
```

But it gets me null for jan.task_hour even though I have that data in my DB.

thanks.

Comment: i think you need intersection table of users and activities is it ?

Comment: No, my tables are linked through USERS id and ACTIVITIES user_id so I know how to get the data for 1 month but I would like to generate a table with every month as column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use join query with conditions [see the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins).